# Writing a batch script which can start up applications

Tags: windows, script, batch

I was just wondering how to write a Windows 7 batch script which can start up a list of applications.

Should look something like this I guess, structurally:

```
Run C://program/software/software1
Run C://program/software/software2
Run C://program/software/software3
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, windows batch starts programmes sequentially - you will want to use the `start` command before each command you want to run - for example

```
start C://program/software/software1
start C://program/software/software2
start C://program/software/software3
```

Which will spawn a new command prompt for each and run it.

Comment: That doesn't work at all. Just opens new command prompts without starting the softwares.

Comment: thats odd. I can't tell based off the example paths, but the paths look a *little* off to me on second thoughts. just to check could you try running start path/to/software1 alone on cmd, using the tab completion to ensure the paths are right? then go on with the second one and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
start "" "Drive:\Path\to\program1\program1.exe"
start "" "Drive:\Path\to\program2\program2.exe"
start "" "Drive:\Path\to\program3\program3.exe"
...
```